# Proving That a Sequence is Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Prove that $\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Workings:

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$

Want $N$ = ____ such that

$\left|\frac{n+1}{n^2} - \frac{m+1}{m^2}\right| < \epsilon$ $(\forall  n,m > N)$

$\left|\frac{n+1}{n^2} - \frac{m+1}{^2m}\right|$

$\leq\left|\frac{n+1}{n^2}\right| + \left|\frac{m+1}{m^2}\right|$

$= \frac{n+1}{n^2} + \frac{m+1}{m^2}$

$= \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$

Now I am not too sure on hwat to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're almost there, now just choose $N$ so that $\frac1n<\frac\epsilon 4$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: $$n,m\gt N\implies\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m^2}\right)\leqslant\frac4N$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To continue, write

$$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m^2} \le \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m} = \frac{2}{n} + \frac{2}{m}.$$

Then note that given $\epsilon$, setting $N > \frac{4}{\epsilon}$ will make $\frac{2}{n} + \frac{2}{m} < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. Thus $$\left|\frac{n + 1}{n^2} - \frac{m + 1}{m^2}\right| < \epsilon$$ for all $n \ge N$.